# Python checking if object member value is in list

Tags: python, list

I have this class called `Point`:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

I have a list with `Point` objects and I call a method to check if it's in the list like this:

```
def isInList(self, list, point):
    for cell in list:
        if(cell == point):
            return True

    return False
```

However, it never goes inside the if statement; so it always returns false. I know for a fact that a point that matches has to be in the list due to a visualization I have showing up in my program. What am I doing wrong?

---

I call these two methods to make a list of `Point`. I pass `cells` and `directions` like this (called multiple times with different points and directions):

```
point = Point(2, 4)
direction = Direction.UP
newList = self.setCells(point, direction)

def setCells(self, point, direction):
    pointList = []
    index = 0
    done = False

    while index < 20 and done == False:
        newPoint = self.getNextCell(point, direction)

        if(point not in pointList):
            pointList.append(newPoint)
            point = pointList[len(pointList)-1]
            index += 1
        else:
            done = True

    return pointList

def getNextCell(self, point, direction):
    if(direction == Direction.UP):
        return Point(point.x-1, point.y, Direction.UP)
    elif(direction == Direction.DOWN):
        return Point(point.x+1, point.y, Direction.DOWN)
    elif(direction == Direction.LEFT):
        return Point(point.x, point.y-1, Direction.LEFT)
    elif(direction == Direction.RIGHT):
        return Point(point.x, point.y+1, Direction.RIGHT)
```

`Direction` is an enum:

```
class Direction(Enum):
    NONE = 1
    UP = 2
    DOWN = 3
    LEFT = 4
    RIGHT = 5
```

Comment: If you know so only by visualisation, could it be that there is a (small) difference between the coordinates of the point in the list and the query point?

Comment: You didn't actually need to write your isInList() function: ``point in myList`` does exactly the same check.

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder Are they not whole numbers? Thanks for letting me know jasonharper!

Comment: They certainly could be, but there is nothing forcing that. Without knowing your other code I have now way of knowing. You could try to change that in the constructor (e.g.  `self.x = int(x)` and `self.y = int(y)`) if that is what you desire.

Comment: I'd also advise you to improve your `__eq__` method (although that is unrelated to your problem). Expecting anything a `Point` might be compared with to be like a point seems unreasonable. Better use `getattr` with a default or `hasattr` or catch the `AttributeError`

Comment: Please read and act on https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  You code does not demonstrate an actual problem: There is no visible test function call, or use of the much better `point in mylist` expression, that gives what you think is an error.  In other words, `p = Point(1, 2); print(p in [p])` prints `True`, just as it should.  On the other hand, `print(p in [Point(1.0000000000001, 2)])` correctly prints `False`.

Comment: @m.o Show how you run the code and what it returns.

Comment: @Nurzhan I added more code. Thanks for the tips JonathanvonSchroeder. I printed out the points and print out the same value but it's still going inside the if statement, regardless.

Comment: Please print point and list inside the function `isInList`,and print its types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the code from the OP's question seems to contain functions that were meant to be bound to an object (`setCells` and `getNextCell`), but are exhibited without their class. Furthermore the call to the constructor of `Point` in `getNextCells` had an additional argument (the direction), which I removed. Therefore I am considering the following code:

import enum

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

def setCells(point, direction):
    pointList = []
    index = 0
    done = False

    while index < 20 and done == False:
        newPoint = getNextCell(point, direction)

        if(point not in pointList):
            pointList.append(newPoint)
            point = pointList[len(pointList)-1]
            index += 1
        else:
            done = True

    return pointList

class Direction(enum.Enum):
    NONE = 1
    UP = 2
    DOWN = 3
    LEFT = 4
    RIGHT = 5

def getNextCell(point, direction):
    if(direction == Direction.UP):
        return Point(point.x-1, point.y)
    elif(direction == Direction.DOWN):
        return Point(point.x+1, point.y)
    elif(direction == Direction.LEFT):
        return Point(point.x, point.y-1)
    elif(direction == Direction.RIGHT):
        return Point(point.x, point.y+1)

point = Point(2, 4)
direction = Direction.UP
newList = setCells(point, direction)
print(point in newList)
```

which prints False. To investigate if this is correct it is useful to add some pretty printing to the class `Point`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Point(%s,%s)" % (self.x,self.y)
```

It is now possible to easily investigate the contents of the list:

```
>>> print(newList)
[Point(1,4)]
>>> print(point)
Point(2,4)
```

Since `newList` contains only one point which has a different x-coordinate it is obvious that `point in newList` should be false.

To better understand why `newList` does not contain `point` it is useful to give a simplified version of setCells:

```
def setCellsSimplified(point,direction):
    return [getNextCell(point, direction)]
```

Explanation: Initially pointList is empty, so `point not in pointList` will be true regardless of the value of `point`. Thus `newPoint` is added to `pointList` and `point` is now equal to `newPoint`. Therefore, when the while-body runs again, `point` is in `pointList` and the second execution is the last execution of the while-body.

Since `getNextCell` always returns a new `Point` that differs in one coordinate from the object passed to it `point` and `getNextCell(point,dir)` are never equal (regardless of the direction) and therefore `point in setCells(point,dir)` is always false (which can be seen easily by looking at the simplified version `setCellsSimplified`).

Comment: Oh man, I really should have learned about pass by value and pass by reference in Python first. Thank you so much! Also, how come it is being modified in 'getNextCell'? I'm not doing an assignment statement in there.

Comment: I probably could have been more clear on that ... What I meant was to say was, that `getNextCell` returns a new Point with one coordinate changed. I just wanted to state that the coordinate will thus be different and not that the object passed to getNextCell is modified in any way. I'll edit the answer to hopefully make this more clear.

Comment: No problem, one problem is that lets say I'm making points going left, then turn up, turn right, turn down, and finally keep going down. I will overlap a point from where I first started. That's what I was trying to avoid. I thought the way I had it would've already had the overlapping point in the list.

Comment: Your condition wouldn't work because you only test if the previous point is not in the list (which, as explained above, is only true if the list is empty). But since you only go in one direction (the direction is never changed in setCells) this can't happen even if you removed the if completely. Simply removing `point = pointList[len(pointList)-1]` should be closer to what you actually wanted. If your algorithm for generating the points does not work as expected please open another question.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I'll open a new question if I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused my how you are invoking this. Your function takes in self, list, and point. If this is a method of an object, and you want to see if the current object is in the list I would try something like this instead...

```
    def isInList(self, list):
        return self in list
```

That should give you an output similar to this...

```
>>> list = [Point(2,2), Point(3,3), Point(4,4)]
>>> x = Point(4,4)
>>> x.isInList(list)
True
>>> x = Point(4,5)
>>> x.isInList(list)
False
```

Comment: Thanks for trying; however, this gives me the same effect as above. I added more code so it might help out.